# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined jquery.easyui.min.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am having a problem with my drag and drop functionality, when i start to drag an item it gives me this error and the error continue to repeat in console till i'm moving my cursor:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'each' of undefined
>   jquery.easyui.min.js

I'm using jeasyui library, here is my code for draggable:

```
var indicator = $('<div class="indicator">>></div>').appendTo('body');  
    $('.gridItem').draggable({ 
        revert:true, 
        proxy:'clone',
        cancel:'div' 
    }).droppable({  
        revert: 'invalid', 
        accept:'.gridItem',
        onDragOver:function(e,source){  
            indicator.css({  
                display:'block',  
                left:$(this).offset().left-10,  
                top:$(this).offset().top+$(this).outerHeight()-5  
            });  
        },  
        onDragLeave:function(e,source){  
            indicator.hide();  
        },  
        onDrop:function(e,source){  
            $(source).insertAfter(this);
            var iterationId=$(this).parent().attr('id');
            indicator.hide(); 
            updateAssignedBacklogRank(iterationId);
        }  
    });
```

Comment: Your __.gridItem__ exist? Can you provide a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: i havent used  $('>>') what are u talking about

Comment: You are attaching easy UI to the selector $('.gridItem'), can you share your HTML markup

Comment: i am making dynamic listitems   $("#"+gridId).append("<li class='gridItem' style='width:355px !important;' id='drop_li_"+id+"'><a style='text-decoration:none' href='#'><p style='display:none'>drop_li_"+id+"</p><input type='text' value='"+id+"' style='display:none;'><div><p style='color:#366898'>"+ formatName(name,60)+"</p><span style='color:#4D4D4D'>Priority: "+priority+"</span><span style='margin-left:20px;color:#4D4D4D'>Type: "+type+"</span><span style='margin-left:20px;color:#4D4D4D'>Resource&nbsp;point: "+ rp +"</span><p style='display:none'>" + gridId + "</p></div></a></li>")

Comment: my problem is solved now, the problem was when i wwas dragging an element and dropping it , then i was sending a call for rank ,and if the user drags the item without waiting for call response that error was coming , i removed the class attribute so that user cant drag until the response comes back.